# I want to change permissions on all folders/files excluding some of them

Tags: permissions, chown

Please refer to the folder hierarchy below.

```
folder1
-> file11.txt
-> file12.txt
-> folder11.backup
   -> file111.txt
   -> file112.txt
   -> file113.bak
   -> folder111
   -> and many more folders and files

folder2
-> file21.txt
-> file22.txt
-> file23.bak

folder2.backup
-> file111.txt
   -> file112.txt
   -> folder111
   -> folder112
      -> file1121.bak
      -> file1122.txt
   -> and many more folders and files

folder3
-> folder31
   -> folder311
      -> folder3111.backup
         -> file3111.txt
         -> file3112.txt
         -> folder3111 
         -> and many more folders and files
      -> folder3112
         -> file31121.bak
         -> file31121.txt
```

I want change the ownership (chown) and permissions (chmod) with the following rules:

1. all folders/subfolders EXCEPT folders that ends in ".backup". In my example folder hierarchy, the **following folders and their contents** will be ignored: folder11.backup, folder2.backup and folder3111.backup
2. all files EXCEPT those that has the extension ".bak". But if the file irrespective of its extension is inside a .backup folder, these are excluded because of rule 1.

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) The directories:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -not -name '*.backup' \
    -not -path '*.backup/*' -print0 | xargs -0 chmod MODE
```

(2) The files:

```
find . -type f -not -name '*.bak' \
    -not -path '*.backup/*' -print0 | xargs -0 chmod MODE
```

For testing you may run the command lines with `ls -ld` instead of `chmod ...`.

Comment: you might use `echo chmod` for testing purpose